# Error 1064 on MySQL 5 database

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I keep getting an error while trying to create a stored procedure.  I am using the following SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_add_mailing_list_item
(
    IN  paramA  VARCHAR(50) ,
    IN  paramB  VARCHAR(50) ,
    IN  paramC  VARCHAR(255)    ,
    IN  paramD  DATE            ,
    IN  paramE  VARCHAR(255)    ,
)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO MailingList
    (
        firstName               ,
        lastName                ,
        email                   ,
        dob                 ,
        notes
    )

VALUES
    (
        paramA              ,
        paramB              ,
        paramC              ,
        paramD              ,
        paramE
    ) 

END
```

I am pretty well versed in SQL (for MSSQL Server), but this is just eluding me.  Any help is appreciated.  I have tried using a delimiter, but that brings up all kinds of other errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting the extra comma on `paramE  VARCHAR(255)    ,` and adding a semicolon at the end of the `VALUES` (before `END`): `paramE);`

Comment: You haven't respond to my comment, but doing what I said works on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7de8

Comment: Sorry, I did actually remove that extra comma form the statement, the same error shows up.

Comment: But did you add the semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

you have an extra comma here

```
   IN  paramE  VARCHAR(255)    ,
```

EDIT: try this .

```
   DELIMITER $$

   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_add_mailing_list_item $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE sp_add_mailing_list_item
 (
  IN  paramA  VARCHAR(50) ,
  IN  paramB  VARCHAR(50) ,
  IN  paramC  VARCHAR(255)    ,
  IN  paramD  DATE            ,
  IN  paramE  VARCHAR(255)    
 )
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MailingList
 (
    firstName               ,
    lastName                ,
    email                   ,
    dob                 ,
    notes
  )

  VALUES
  (
    paramA              ,
    paramB              ,
    paramC              ,
    paramD              ,
    paramE
  ) 
    END $$
    DELIMITER
```

Comment: Is there anything else, as I corrected that, I now get that same error.  When my PHP Admin shows me the query, it doesn't show the end statement.  Thanks.

Comment: Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_add_mailing_list_item $$
   CREA' at line 1